# Regex that match any character inside a parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

Trying to create a regex that match any character inside a parentheis.

My regex pattern is this

```
preg_match('/\((.*?)\)/', $listanswer, $answer);
```

All string inside the parenthesis is the matching pattern. But the problem is, when I try to match eg,. `(this word), (sample data)` it only returns null. When if no space added, it is matched. Any idea on this?

Already tested it here. http://regex101.com

It worked just fine. Did i miss something>?

Comment: What programming language do you plan to use? Will you have `(Nested (parentheses))`?

Comment: I am using PHP, and no nested parenthesis

Comment: `.` matches space too, could you post the whole code that could reproduce your problem?

Comment: Okay. Do you want to match `(the parentheses too)`, or just (`what's inside?`)

Comment: have you tried preg_match_all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
\(([^)]+)\)
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://rubular.com/r/6FDuE3FEfb)**

- `\(` : match an opening parentheses
- `(` : begin capturing group
- `[^)]+`: match one or more non `)` characters
- `)` : end capturing group
- `\)` : match closing parentheses

Comment: seems like it has the same issue,. I tried to var_dump the matching value.. all I got was null,

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have `(nested (parentheses))` in your input:

To match `(the parentheses too)` use `\([^)]*\)` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/sD5vQ6))

To just match (`what's inside?`) use `(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))` ([demo](http://regex101.com/r/xW8mX8))

1. The first one just match an opening parens, any chars that are not a closing parens, and a closing par.
2. The second one uses a lookbehind and a lookahead. First the `(?<=\()` lookbehind asserts that what precedes is an opening parenthesis. Then we match any chars that are not a closing parens. Then the `(?=\))` lookahead asserts that what follows is an closing parenthesis.