# A little more help for "Regex that match any character inside a parenthesis"

Tags: javascript, regex

I asked a related question [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135006/regex-that-match-any-character-inside-a-parenthesis), and it helped me very much.

I used this code:

```
function extractUsers(usersArray) {
    var i; // loop counter
    for (i = 0; i < usersArray.length; i++) {

        if (/\(([^)]+)\)/.test(usersArray[i])) {
            // retrieves the user id from strings like "name (ID)"
            usersArray[i] = RegExp.$1;
            console.log('in the regexloop ' + i + ' of ' + usersArray.length + ' and test. current value: ' + usersArray[i]);
        }
        //console.log('the cleaned usersArray ' + usersArray);
    }
    return usersArray;
}
```

For the user array: "Carin Nilsson-Thorell (CARIN.NILSSON-T),Maria Bengzon (MARIA.BENGZON),Therese Rick (THERESE.RICK),Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)"

the console log showed:

```
selected is Carin Nilsson-Thorell (CARIN.NILSSON-T),Maria Bengzon (MARIA.BENGZON),Therese Rick (THERESE.RICK),Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)
in the regexloop 0 of 4 and test. current value: CARIN.NILSSON-T
in the regexloop 1 of 4 and test. current value: MARIA.BENGZON
in the regexloop 2 of 4 and test. current value: THERESE.RICK
in the regexloop 3 of 4 and test. current value: IPEINTECK
extracted selected is CARIN.NILSSON-T,MARIA.BENGZON,THERESE.RICK,IPEINTECK
```

Which is exactly what I hoped for.
But when the user array was just one user, "Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)"
the console log showed

```
selected is Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)
extracted selected is Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)
```

So it seems it doesn't even enter the "if" statement? How come?

I even tried https://regex101.com/ and there it works ok...

I also tried the /(?<=()[^)]*(?=))/ version, but that threw some error about the ? (Forgot to capture that error. Trying to reproduce it now, throws me other errors - I'll add the error text as soon as I can...)

I am still trying to learn all I can about JavaScript, but I do stumble.

### Edit

This is the "parent function" that calls the extractUsers function:

```
    function assignStepUsers() {
    var element = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.route.stepnumber');
    var stepNumber = element.value;
    console.log('running form assignStepUsers. stepNumber is ' + stepNumber);
    var selected = []; // array. holds the current value of users within a set of statements. set to empty for each stepNumber run.
    var i; //loop counter
    var pad = "00"; //size of id number
    var id; // id number of cause
    var counter; // what thing are we counting
    var selector; // what elements to select and count
    var nr; // how many things are launched (document.getElementById(counter).value)
    var things; // how many things in tota l (document.querySelectorAll(selector))
    var owner; // holds the current task owner within a set of statements
    var field; // the select field that holds all users of a step, with selected users highlighted
    var end; // length of field, for loop end.

    //var step2Users, step3Users, step4Users, step5Users, step6Users, step7Users, step8Users, step9Users, step10Users, step11Users, step12Users;
    // for preview, add "|| stepNumber == 0 || NaN(stepNumber)" after "stepNumber == 1" inside parenthesis
    if ((stepNumber == 1 ) && (document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Owner').value !='' && document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Coordinator').value != '')) { // removed || stepNumber == 0 || NaN(stepNumber), for troubleshooting/form preview only
        console.log('assignStepusers for Step 1 . selected CAPA Owner = ' + document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Owner').value +  ' selected CAPA Coord = ' + document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Coordinator').value);

        // assign QM and CAPA owner to step 2, 6, 8, 10, 12

        // find all content of the QM role field (QMOptions), then push values into array (QM)
        var QMOptions = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.role.QM').querySelectorAll('option');
        console.log('QMOptions length = ' + QMOptions.length);
        var QM = []; // array for all the QM users
        var oneQM; // the current QM user of the field
        for (i = 0; i < QMOptions.length; i++) {
            oneQM = QMOptions[i].value;
            QM.push(oneQM);
            console.log('QM is now ' + QM);
        }

        selected = QM;
        console.log('selected is ' + selected);

        var capaOwner = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Owner').value;
        selected.push(capaOwner);
        console.log('selected is ' + selected);

        extractUsers(selected);
        console.log('extracted selected is ' + selected);
        sortUsers(selected);
        console.log('sorted selected is ' + selected);

        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step2', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step6', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step8', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step10', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step12', selected);

        // assign ONLY capa owner to step 4 
        selected = capaOwner; // QM users are removed.
        console.log('selected is ' + selected); 
        extractUsers(selected);
        // no need for sortUsers, only one in array.
        console.log('extracted selected is ' + selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step4', selected);

        //assign CAPA Coordinator to 3,5,7,9,11
        var capaCoord = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Coordinator').value;
        selected = capaCoord;
        console.log('selected is ' + selected);
        extractUsers(selected);
        // no need for sortUsers, only one in array.
        console.log('extracted selected is ' + selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step3', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step5', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step7', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step9', selected);
        setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step11', selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that isn't behaving as you expect? Maybe in a JSFiddle so that we can replicate?

Comment: it's the extractUsers function that I included above...

Comment: But how you call it exactly? Like `console.log(extractUsers(["Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)"]));` for example?

Comment: Or did you mean the function that calls the extractUsers function?

Comment: Beware using the `RegExp.$1`, as it is non-standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n. In general, you should capture the match of a regex using the `match` method of a string.

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni : yes, I did read that, but couldn't work out how to use the match method... still such a newbie at this!

Comment: @MariaBenzin I am unable to replicate the issue, see fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xag3huvo/)

Comment: The extractUsers function is working if called with the correct arguments (`console.log(extractUsers(['Inti van Eck (IPEINTECK)']))`). Check the arguments you are passing to it!

Comment: @UnbearableLightness it does seem strange, doesn't it? When I try online tests for the string, I can't replicate the error either...

Comment: @GavinoGrifoni 
the CAPA Owner and CAPA Coordinator are <select> elements, where only one <option> can be selected.
the QM element is a <select> with four <option> elements, and all are selected.
I use a little loop to put the value of each option into an array.

var capaOwner is the value of the CAPA_owner <select> element, and it can be pushed into the array, just after the QM array has been assigned to the selected variable, so I thought that the later assignment
selected = capaOwner; would still mean that selected is an array. Perhaps that's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It was the arguments passed to the function, more precisely here:

```
    // assign ONLY capa owner to step 4 
    selected = capaOwner; // QM users are removed. //<---- this was wrong!
    console.log('selected is ' + selected); 
    extractUsers(selected);
    // no need for sortUsers, only one in array.
    console.log('extracted selected is ' + selected);
    setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step4', selected);

    //assign CAPA Coordinator to 3,5,7,9,11
    var capaCoord = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Coordinator').value;
    selected = capaCoord; //<---- this was wrong!
    console.log('selected is ' + selected);
    extractUsers(selected);
```

When I used this instead:

```
    // assign ONLY capa owner to step 4 
    selected = []; // empty the variable array again.
    selected.push(capaOwner);  // just add the capaOwner, which was defined above, to the array. (because having just selected = capaOwner failed.)
    console.log('selected is ' + selected); 
    extractUsers(selected);
    // no need for sortUsers, only one in array.
    console.log('extracted selected is ' + selected);
    setStepUsers('mastercontrol.route.stepusers.step4', selected);

    //assign CAPA Coordinator to 3,5,7,9,11
    var capaCoord = document.getElementById('mastercontrol.set.CAPA_Coordinator').value;
    //selected = capaCoord;
    selected = []; // empty the variable array again.
    selected.push(capaCoord);  // just add the capaCoord, which was defined above, to the array. (because having just selected = capaCoord failed.)
    console.log('selected is ' + selected);
    extractUsers(selected);
```

it went just as I hoped!

Today's lesson: if you want an array to stay an array, don't simply assign a string value  to it. Use the .push method.

Thanks all!